# Any way to use jQuery or JS to force load order of assets of page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have this site http://www.wiredintel.jigsy.com/. The problem is they have their php and ajax improperly configured, nothing on my end I don't think. The page despite all i've tried, doesn't render for at least 4-5 seconds. I am really wondering if there is anything at all I can do, using sometime of jQuery or JavaScript to force the load order or at least delay the assets from loading. I ran a performance test in chrome dev tools. The page gets stuck on a lot of unnecessary things in the beginning.

Things I've tried:

1. CSS animation delay
2. setTimeout(function() {...}, 3000);
3. window.onpageshow=function(){...}

I've only tried my attempts on the assets I added, not sure how to target them to the assets they setup such as other jQuery files, font and image files.

Comment: Have you looked in the network load times for all assets? If it's large files / images bogging you down or a slow server response, Javascript won't fix that. You could maybe try to leverage caching but that might not solve your problems.

Comment: The slowdown I'm seeing with that site, is everything before I even get the first document response. So I am thinking its a server load issue, or a bad database query (no indexes?) or something in the script.

Comment: I'd go in and do some microtime peppering in the php to see where the biggest bogdown happens. Then focus on that piece of code. Maybe you are doing file_get_contents in the php that is pulling from an external resource that is slow... or a curl operation of the like... or anything. I can only guess, since I don't see your php code.

Comment: note: i don't have access to the ajax or php

Comment: Well thats gonna make things difficult ;)

Comment: Updated: I switched to bravenet.com, their CMS system is identical and their services load faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a network timing log on a fresh visit to the linked website on Google Chrome:

[image: NetworkTiming]

We can see from the gigantic green bar at the top, that **almost all of your load time is consumed in server processing to deliver the html.** All the other assets are pretty quick and mostly parallelized.

By [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law), we know that optimizing parts of a process that are already fast will yield negligible results. So any caching/lazy-loading/pre-loading/load-order trickery you want to try probably won't even make a noticeable difference in your case.

**Making javascript changes on the front end will make no difference to your server side processing latency.** You have to fix this problem on the server side. You said you don't have access to the php, so that makes this harder. This may be a configuration setting that is causing this. Or it could be that jigsy.com just sucks, either through poor code backend or overcrowding of their servers. Either way, you will either need to work this out with jigsy (they could point to any misconfigurations on your part or perhaps you could pay to upgrade your service?) or move to another provider.